# Url rewrite from .htaccess with Get variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working in a project in PHP , I am not using MVC but keeping a single `index.php` files which changes it's content based on `$_GET['module']`

My current url format is

```
http://phpquiz.com/school/index.php?module=user_groups&mid=13&cmid=32
```

Now i want to change it to

```
http://phpquiz.com/school/index/user_groups/13/32
```

I used following script and was able to rewrite url but my site stopped working as it lost get variables.

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/school/index.php [NC]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^module=(.*)&mid=(.*)&cmid=(.*)
 RewriteRule (.*) http://phpquiz.com/school/%1/%2/%3.asp? [R=301,L]
```

How can i do this by keeping get vatiables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/school/index.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^module=([^&]+)&mid=([^&]+)&cmid=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ http://local.htaccess/school/index.php/%1/%2/%3.asp? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing reverse. Have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^school/index\.php/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.asp$ /school/index.php?module=$1&mid=$2&cmid=$3 [NC,QSA,L]
```